# Cursor/caret bleeding through overlay in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am doing work on and existing website www.shopthethirdfloor.com.  Using IE, if you click on the products menu, give focus to the search box and then scroll the search field under the menu overlay that pops up, the search field goes under the overlay, but the cursor continues to blink where the hidden input field is.  This only happens in IE.  The search and product display is an iframe also.  I am thinking this is an ie bug/feature depending if you are a user or microsoft.

Comment: If you want debugging help, rather than just pointing to a live web site which may change at any time, you need to post the relevant code to reproduce the issue in the question itself.

Comment: This is an IE bug and isn't specific for your site. Probably microsoft will call it a feature and say it is a "Feature to assist to find the cursor location when hidden under another element."

Comment: Thanks for the info.  That is what I suspected, but could not find any information on it.

Comment: try `$(textbox).blur()` when the overlay pops up

Comment: Is there a way to say if textbox not visible then $(textbox).blur().  If would want to do something that would only do that in the event that it got covered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I work on the Internet Explorer team, and can assure you that we don't view this as a feature. It's a bug, plain and simple. I've added this question, and your site, to an internal ticket on the issue for the team to review during the next triage.

For the time being you could add a check for the `document.documentMode`, and apply a bit of functionality to prevent Internet Explorer from showing the caret over the top of unrelated elements. In the following code I use jQuery's [`$.fn.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to attach a one-time-use handler during an element's `.onFocus` event, and then dispose of it during the window's `.onScroll` event:

```js
if ( document.documentMode && document.documentMode < 12 ) {
    $( document ).on( "focus", ":input", function ( event ) {
        $( window ).one( "scroll", function () {
            event.target.blur();
        });
    });
}
```

The results can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/yynsbrat/2/

I'll continue to work with the team on resolving this issue from our end, but until this I hope this approach is able to help you in the interim.

Comment: This issue is still occurring in IE11, do you have any information if this will be fixed?

Comment: We are no longer servicing Internet Explorer browsers with updates like this. Supported versions of IE will continue to get security updates. Should we resolve this issue, the fix will land in Microsoft Edge. At this time, I don't have any information about when a fix will land.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Thanks.

Comment: @Sampson any suggestions for those who are using react JS? you know, adding a jQuery code to a React JS app is a no no.

Comment: @Mawaheb just use React ref and bind it to the scroll event

Comment: This continues to be a bug in Edge too, and furthermore blur does not work in that browser.

Comment: This fix is ruining our sites accessibility this it is not possible to tab though forms which do not fit in the screen since the fields loose focus on page scroll. Please do the proper fix in the browser itself!